# What do these blood tests mean in general and why do doctors ask for them before taking action?

Tags: blood, blood-tests, gerd-acid-reflux

My doctor ordered some blood tests for me.  I would like to understand what each test is for, meaning what information could be gathered from the results.

- W.B.C.
- Platelets
- E.S.R.
- C.R.P.
- Alpha feto protein
- C.E.A.

I have read that some of these, such as CRP, are no longer relevant or often used. Is that true?

Comment: This is asking for personal diagnosis and considered off-topic on Health.SE. One option is to ask what each number (creatinine, hemoglobin etc.) does to the body. Health.SE is a site that will help you understand health related body processes, not an internet doctor!

Comment: Ok sir I change the question see the edit.

Comment: I read someone said that CRP is irrelevant and useless. Is that true ? And does CRP detect infection in any part of the body without specifiying where it is the infection ? I edited the question

Comment: I think that if you merely asked what the tests are for, rather than an interpretation of the specific results, this could be a good question.

Comment: I completely overhauled the question.  The awesome answer deserves a well phrased question.  I removed all medical advice and converted it into an inquiry on purpose for tests.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Thanks for the laudatory ;). I personally am disappointed that my answers about masturbation receive so many upvotes and well-more time investing and more helpful answers like this so little. If I had a choice, I would switch the votes. But I guess that's what people care about...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### CRP

> C-reactive protein (CRP) is produced by the liver. The level of CRP rises when there is inflammation throughout the body. It is one of a group of proteins called "acute phase reactants" that go up in response to inflammation.

So, when there is an inflammation anywhere in your body, the amount of C-reactive protein in your blood will rise.

The CRP test is a general test to check for inflammation in the body. It is not a specific test. That means it can reveal that you have inflammation somewhere in your body, but it cannot pinpoint the exact location.

*Source: [Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003356.htm)*

**Test Results**

1. For Inflammation:

   > A test result showing a CRP level greater than 10 mg/L is a sign of serious infection, trauma or chronic disease, which likely will require further testing to determine the cause.
2. For Heart Diseases

   > If you're having an hs-CRP test to evaluate your risk of heart disease, there is a high risk if you have an hs-CRP level greater than 2.0 mg/L.

*Source: [MayoClinic.org](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/c-reactive-protein/basics/results/PRC-20014480)*

---

### ESR

> ESR stands for erythrocyte sedimentation rate. It is commonly called a "sed rate." [...]
>   This test can be used to monitor inflammatory diseases or cancer. **It is not used to diagnose a specific disorder.**
>   *(Emphasis mine)*

Basically, they measure how long red blood cells (erythrocytes) take to travel down a thin  tube.

*Source: [Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003638.htm)*

**Test Results**

> Results from your sed rate test will be reported in the distance in millimeters (mm) that red blood cells have descended in one hour (hr). The normal range is 0-22 mm/hr for men and 0-29 mm/hr for women. The upper threshold for a normal sed rate value may vary somewhat from one medical practice to another.

*Source: [MayoClinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/sed-rate/details/results/rsc-20207039)*

---

### AFP

> An alpha-fetoprotein (AFP) blood test checks the level of AFP in a pregnant woman's blood. AFP is a substance made in the liver of an unborn baby (fetus).

This is a very solid indication whether one is pregnant or not. It can also help to asses the health of the fetus.

If one is not pregnant, it is highly probable that there are problems with the liver if a high amount of AFP can be found in the blood.

*Source: [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/baby/alpha-fetoprotein-afp-in-blood)*

**Test Results**

> For women who aren’t pregnant as well as men, the normal amount of AFP is usually less than 10 nanograms per milliliter of blood. If your AFP level is unusually high but you aren’t pregnant, it may indicate the presence of certain cancers or liver diseases.

*Source: [Healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com/health/alpha-fetoprotein#results5)*

---

### CEA

> The carcinoembryonic antigen (CEA) test measures the amount of this protein that may appear in the blood of some people who have certain kinds of cancers, especially cancer of the large intestine (colon and rectal cancer). It may also be present in people with cancer of the pancreas, breast, ovary, or lung.

This protein is usually only produced in the fetus, so a high level of CEA in the blood can be linked to cancer.

*Source: [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/cancer/carcinoembryonic-antigen-cea)*

**Test Results**

> The normal range is 0 to 2.5 micrograms per liter (mcg/L). In smokers, the normal range is 0 to 5 mcg/L.

*Source: [Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003574.htm)*

---

### WBC

The White Blood Cell  Count (WBC) determines the amount of leukocytes, or white blood cells in your blood.

The leukocytes play a vital role in your immune system. Generalized:

> These cells help fight infections by attacking bacteria, viruses, and germs that invade the body.
>
> Having a higher or lower number of WBCs than normal may be an indication of an underlying condition. A WBC count can detect hidden infections within your body and alert doctors to undiagnosed medical conditions, such as autoimmune diseases, immune deficiencies, and blood disorders.

This is a standard part of any blood test.

*Source: [healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com/health/wbc-count#overview1)*

**Test Results**

> The normal number of WBCs in the blood is 4,500 to 11,000 white blood cells per microliter (mcL) or 4.5 to 11.0 x 10^9/L.
>
> Normal value ranges may vary slightly among different labs. Some labs use different measurements or may test different specimens. Talk to your doctor about your test results.

*Source: [Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003643.htm)*

---

### RBC

> An RBC count is a blood test that measures how many red blood cells (RBCs) you have.
>
> RBCs contain hemoglobin, which carries oxygen. How much oxygen your body tissues get depends on how many RBCs you have and how well they work.

This is a standard part of any blood test.

*Source: [Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003644.htm)*

**Test Results**

> A normal range in adults is generally considered to be 700,000 to 5.2 million red blood cells per microliter (mcL) of blood for men and 500,000 to 4.6 million red blood cells per mcL of blood for women. In children, the threshold for high red blood cell count varies with age and sex.

*Source: [MayoClinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/high-red-blood-cell-count/basics/definition/SYM-20050858)*

---

### Platelet Count

> Platelets are parts of the blood that help the blood clot. They are smaller than red or white blood cells.
>
> The number of platelets in your blood can be affected by many diseases. Platelets may be counted to monitor or diagnose diseases, or to look for the cause of too much bleeding or clotting.

This is a standard part of any blood test.

*Source: [Medlineplus.org](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003647.htm)*

**Test Results**

> A normal platelet count is between 150,000 and 450,000 platelets per microliter (one-millionth of a liter, abbreviated mcL). The average platelet count is 237,000 per mcL in men and 266,000 per mcL in women.
>
> A platelet count below 150,000 per mcL is called thrombocytopenia, while a platelet count over 450,000 is called thrombocytosis. Platelets seem to have a large backup capacity: blood typically still clots normally as long as the platelet count is above 50,000 per mcL (assuming no other problems are present). Spontaneous bleeding doesn’t usually occur unless the platelet count falls to 10,000 or 20,000 per mcL.

*Source: [WebMD Answers](http://answers.webmd.com/answers/1198204/what-is-a-normal-platelet-count)*

Comment: I am a male..so generally my test are good. No cancers, inflammations, heart diseases right ?

Comment: I am not going to diagnose you here. It does look good, nevertheless, **it is vital to make another appointment to your doctor**. Even if you have to pay money for that, your health and life should be worth it. The pain and coughing may be symptoms of lethal diseases only a doctor will recognize.

Comment: Yeah I did. So just make me relax. On paper my test is good ?

Comment: On paper, your doctor can rule out inflammation. (Cancer and heart disease are very very unlikely and the tests were probably only done to rule out inflammation). This means that instead of a viral infect, a bacterial infect could lead to your symptoms. The doctor will try to find out if it is in fact a bacterial infect and which bacterial infect it is.

Comment: Thanks Narusan. Bacterial infect I think is dangerous too. Thank you Narusan you make me relaxed and understand why my doctor asks for those tests. And thanks god thatvthe result are good enough to eliminate some dangerous disease.

Comment: Usually, cancer/heart disease isn't recognized with these tests. A test result indicating cancer is just **one of many symptoms**. Inflammation is much more likely.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You said high level of ESR can detect certain type of cancers. Now you're saying that cancer isn't recognised with these tests

Comment: In my answer, I am saying that cancer can lead to high levels of ESR. However, this **doesn't mean that you must have cancer if high levels of ESR are present**. It **doesn't mean that you don't have cancer when ESR is not high** either. From my experience, most cancers are not diagnosed solely by looking at the ESR value. You can see this from the extract *it is not used to diagnose a certain disease* in my answer. I have edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Why the doctor asked for all those tests and they are not even relevant because if high that does not mean a fatal disease and vice versa. Why he didn't said directly go and make scan or echo or something relevant. Stupid doctors that they just want to make money

Comment: You need to read my statement more carefully. This test is done to find out whether you have an inflammation (which is a symptom of multiple problems/diseases). No scan will be able to show that. Plus, a blood test is the cheapest test available.

Comment: Now I am more anxious. God knows. I only have reflux and little pain in my stomach that isn't annoying. Oh god :(

Comment: @AhmadAli  Well, your doctor now can rule out inflammation. That's why the tests were done. And, as said before, cancer or heart diseases are unlikely.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me some positive vibes. I will see my doctor Monday. Lets hope that everything goes well.